# having trouble opening a file?

Tags: c++

I don't know what exactly the issue is.  I get an error saying that I need to initialize my char* filename but if i initialize it to NULL I get another error too?

I have this in my main function:

```
char * filename;
cout << "Enter the name of the graph file: ";
cin >> filename;
readgraph(filename, 1);
```

And  here is the readgraph function:

Comment: I take it this is supposed to be C, not C++.

Comment: @Beta It's some kind of strange hybrid. There is no `std::cout` and `std::cin` in C, but no idea why anyone wouldn't use `std::string` in C++.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a pointer just *points* to a space containing memory. In your code, **filename** is (handwaving here) a pointer to an array of characters, but you never actually gave it anything to point to.

You can initialize it with a particular size:

```
char filename[50]; // An array that can hold 49 characters plus a NULL terminator
```

Or a dynamic size:

```
size_t size = whatever_you_want;
char *filename = new char[whatever_you_want];
// make sure to delete[] filename when you're done
```

You should be aware though, that if you try to put more data in the string than it was allocated to hold, it will cause a huge security hole called a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which (if you're lucky) will cause your program to crash.

Or you can do it the easy way and use `string`:

```
string filename;
cin >> filename;
```

This last way is probably the best, since you don't need to worry about buffer overflow errors like you would if you handle the string size yourself, and you don't need to deal with `delete`ing it when you're done, since `string` handles that automatically for you.

You can always convert to a C string (`char*`) using the [`c_str()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/), but I'd advise only using that for backwards compatibility with functions that can't handle `string` parameters.

Comment: Agreed, I would use a string as well (unless you have some reason not too?).